# Outlining a defect in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have the following image on which i have applied bilateral filtering and subtracted it from my original image

Is it possible to outline the glass defect as shown

[image]

After apply Hough i got the following result not perfect :/

[image]

My matlab code :

```
  im = imread('C:\Users\SUJIT\Desktop\image003.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(im);
h = fspecial('gaussian', size(im), 1.0);
g = imfilter(im, h);

im=im2double(g);

im=imadjust(im);
imgauss = imfilter(im, fspecial('gaussian',[7 7], 6),'conv');
imbi = bilateralfilter(im, [5 5], 3, 3);
imbi= im - imbi;


 imshow(imbi,[]); title('Bilateral Filted Image');

I = imcrop(imbi, [30 30 450 350]);
J = imfilter(I, fspecial('gaussian', [17 17], 5), 'symmetric');
BW = edge(J, 'canny');

%# Hough Transform and show matrix
[H T R] = hough(BW);
imshow(imadjust(mat2gray(H)), [], 'XData',T, 'YData',R, ...
       'InitialMagnification','fit')
xlabel('\theta (degrees)'), ylabel('\rho')
axis on, axis normal, hold on
colormap(hot), colorbar

%# detect peaks
P  = houghpeaks(H, 10);
plot(T(P(:,2)), R(P(:,1)), 'gs', 'LineWidth',2);

%# detect lines and overlay on top of image
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);
figure, imshow(I), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'g.-', 'LineWidth',2);
end
hold off
```

Please help am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to give a general answer based on only one image and no other information, but I can give a specific answer based on your sample image.

Assuming that what you want to find is the vertical blurry line in the middle of the image, this my approach. I won't go into specific implementation details, but only an outline on how I would do it.

1. Find the windows. There are multiple approaches to this. Some ideas are to either find the corners, or to find the rectangular structure itself. The Hough transform is a possible tool.
2. For each window, check if there are vertical structures in it.

Comment: No, you haven't. You have only extracted the lines in the image. You have not tried to identify the area that is the glass pane.

Comment: You probably need to first extract the window. Then rerun the hough transform and/or edge detector using a different threshold.

Comment: How do i extact the window from the image any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Find four corners that make up the window. You will have many corners, so you will have to use some kind of heuristic to determine which corners make up a window. The lines you get out of the hough transform might be helpful as well.